# nggrid how can I disable/enable individual column

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a nggrid with a name and an age column with some data.

so it looks like this:

```
Name | Age
50 | 50 : age field has green background because name and age col have same value
```

How can I make the age column editable/noneditable depending on the namecolumn value in this row?

see also: http://plnkr.co/edit/OxJqS5LYOvG2vx0Ujhu7?p=preview

Comment: why not just use the enableCellEdit or enableCellEditOnFocus in your nggrid options? does the requirement insist on only making it editable when there is an issue?

Comment: I need to have this age column disabled ie enableCellEdit=false, but this does not work: enableCellEdit:row.getProperty(col.field) == row.getProperty('name') see updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/jFKJvC7ShAiN95ro0Tz0?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cellEditableCondition` on a per-column basis within the columnDefs like so:

```
cellEditableCondition: 'row.getProperty(\'name\') == row.getProperty(\'age\')'
```

See [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kFGgE3KPbceKoeKPG0vn?p=preview). If you want to control editing on a per-row basis, move `cellEditableCondition` out of the columnDefs and into the gridOptions.