# cellEditableCondition always returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to get a grid on a website to allow the user the ability to edit cell values for only certain properties.  I'm sorry if this is basic level, but I'm new to this type of advanced website design.

I've been looking around and found two previous questions that I tried to draw my functionality from:

- [How to find if an array contains a specific string in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116474/how-to-find-if-an-array-contains-a-specific-string-in-javascript-jquery)
- [nggrid how can I disable/enable individual column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054427/nggrid-how-can-i-disable-enable-individual-column)

Combining these, I created the following code so that any row that has "Value" equal to anything in my noneditable list will not be open for the user to change:

```
noneditable = [ "hamburger", "fries" ]

$scope.gridOptions = {
        data : 'gridData',
        enableRowSelection : false,
        enableCellEditOnFocus : true,
        showFooter : true,
        columnDefs : [ {
            field : 'name',
            displayName : 'Parameter',
            enableCellEdit : false
        }, {
            field : 'value',
            displayName : 'Value',
            /**enableCellEdit : true**/
            cellEditableCondition : '$.inArray(row.getProperty(\'value\'), noneditable) == -1'
        } ]
    };
```

I'm running this, and its compiling, but all cells in column "Value" are noneditable, even the ones contained in the list (tried both > -1 and == -1 to see if I had just gotten the logic wrong, but both produce the same results).  Any thoughts?  And thank you in advance.

---

UPDATE (3/27/15):
I was unable to find the solution to this problem, instead I worked around it by just adding another property on the list of values to be displayed.  My operational code is:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data : 'gridData',
        enableRowSelection : false,
        enableCellEditOnFocus : true,
        showFooter : true,
        columnDefs : [ {
            field : 'name',
            displayName : 'Parameter',
            enableCellEdit : false
        }, {
            field : 'value',
            displayName : 'Value',
            cellEditableCondition : 'row.getProperty(\'editable\')'
        }]
    };
```

I'm just posting this code in case it helps someone else out.

Comment: did you tried `indexOf` instead of `$.inArray`

Comment: Same results when I use the line `'cellEditableCondition : 'noneditable.indexOf(row.getProperty(\'value\')) == -1'`